# Is there a way to apply styles to columns in a p:selectManyMenu?

Tags: java, css, primefaces

Is there a way to apply styles to columns in a p:selectManyMenu?

```
<!-- Cut down version of the code -->
<p:selectManyMenu id="myMenu" value="#{myBean.myEntries}" 
        var="ent" converter="#{EntriesConverter}"
        showCheckbox="true" styleClass="valign-middle mapMenu" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.entryList}" var="entry" itemValue="#{entry}" />
    <p:column styleClass="css_id">#{entry.id}</p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="css_name">#{entry.name}</p:column>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

The generated code does not include the css_id and css_name and so I can't see a good way of applying css styling to the columns :(

Am I missing something or is it not possible? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is this code from and for, I am unfamiliar with this syntax. In CSS for HTML the selector 'p>p' would target your inner columns

Comment: @Timidfriendly This is primefaces xhtml - it gets translated into html when a user makes a request. The p tags are not <p> but in fact denote the primefaces namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to control the column width in a rather roundabout way:

```
/* MyStylesheet.css */

.mapMenu 
{
  height: 200px;
  width: inherit ! important;
}
.mapMenu table 
{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.mapMenu table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1) 
{
  width: 20px;
}
.mapMenu table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(2) 
{
  width: 50px;
}
```

It's probably not the best way of doing it, but until an alternative arises it'll have to do.